# Bulkd trigger skips some records

Tags: trigger, data-loader, bulk-api

I have an object that I upsert using Dataloader, that has a unique external ID but the same ID must be used as a lookup to another object.
Sadly, in Dataloader, you cannot assign a value to two fields. Therefore I wrote a trigger. This seems to work but only on a few records. For other records, the lookup remains empty.
The strange thing is, that when I run the dataloader again (thus update), some of the empty lookups, but not all, are filled and when I run it again, even more are filled, so it seems as if the trigger is only run on some records, not all at the same time.

I think it has something to do with Dataloader Bulk API but I'm not sure.

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger ServiceMaxCoveredProductTrigger on SVMXC__Service_Contract_Products__c (before insert, before update) 
    {
        Map<Id,String> machineNumbers = new Map<Id,String>();
        for ( SVMXC__Service_Contract_Products__c coveredProduct : (List<SVMXC__Service_Contract_Products__c>) Trigger.new)
        {
            machineNumbers.put(coveredProduct.Id, coveredProduct.Navision_Machine_Relatie_Nr__c);
        } 
        Map<string, Id> products = new Map<string, Id>(); 
        for ( SVMXC__Installed_Product__c installedProduct : [SELECT Id, Navision_Machine_Nummer__c  FROM SVMXC__Installed_Product__c WHERE Navision_Machine_Nummer__c IN : machineNumbers.values()] )
        {
            products.put(installedProduct.Navision_Machine_Nummer__c , installedProduct.Id);
        }

        for ( SVMXC__Service_Contract_Products__c product : (List<SVMXC__Service_Contract_Products__c>)Trigger.new )
        {
            product.SVMXC__Installed_Product__c = products.get(product.Navision_Machine_Relatie_Nr__c);
        }
    }
```

and these are my Dataloader options

[image]

Comment: Your trigger code is incomplete. Would you post the rest of it please?

Comment: ok, I updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that your problem lies in this line:

```
machineNumbers.put(coveredProduct.Id, coveredProduct.Navision_Machine_Relatie_Nr__c);
```

In case of **before insert**, a record has no `Id`, so you basically call

```
machineNumbers.put(null, coveredProduct.Navision_Machine_Relatie_Nr__c);
```

Which will work and won't give errors, but it will overwrite existing records in your map that had no `Id`(with other words: which had `null` as their key).

I just tested it with simple piece of code in dev console:

```
Map<String, String> tempMap = new Map<String, String>();
tempMap.put(null, 'test1');
tempMap.put(null, 'test2');
tempMap.put(null, 'test3');
tempMap.put('4', 'test4');
System.debug('tempMap: ' + tempMap);
```

And got the following output:

> 08:08:04:027 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|tempMap: {null=test3, 4=test4}

To fix it I would change it to **after insert**

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query on the line below before you enter the for loop and get the results first, especially since you already have everything you need:

```
for ( SVMXC__Installed_Product__c installedProduct : [SELECT Id, Navision_Machine_Nummer__c  FROM SVMXC__Installed_Product__c WHERE Navision_Machine_Nummer__c IN : machineNumbers.values()] ){
```

As its written now, I suspect this query is running for every record. You'd need to check your debug log to see for certain, but it really only needs to be run once. This could easily be the source of your problem, making your trigger run very slow. Your trigger might be causing your DataLoader to time out as a result. You may want to look at your debug log to see if that's the case.

So, do something like this:

```
   list<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c>qinstProduct = new list<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c>(); 
   qinstProduct = [SELECT Id, Navision_Machine_Nummer__c  FROM SVMXC__Installed_Product__c WHERE Navision_Machine_Nummer__c IN : machineNumbers.values()];

   // Now run the for loop

   for ( SVMXC__Installed_Product__c installedProduct : qinstProduct)
   {
      products.put(installedProduct.Navision_Machine_Nummer__c , installedProduct.Id);
   }
```